# Are there free websites on Windows Azure for more than the trial period

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I did a lot of searching but I guess Windows Azure's trial offers are constantly changing and there is a lot of different information over the internet. I am looking to develop a small website for learning purposes using Azure. My questions are:

1) Are there still 10 free websites after my 30-day trial ends?

If yes,

2) Can I use Table/Blob store after the trial period?

3) Can I use Azure SQL instance after the trial period?

Comment: All table/blob storage must be converted to a paid account after the trial to access them. (Dont just create new storage, convert the old).  I'm sure Azure SQL is the same.  Dont know about the websites, but probably the pattern holds.  Have you looked into BizSpark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the horses mouth, so to speak:

[Web Sites Pricing Details](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/)

You can run up to 10 websites for Free in a shared environment.

Azure Table Storage will cost, but it's not all that much.  [Storage Pricing Details](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/) gives you a run down, but I find their [Pricing Calculator](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=data-management) to be quite useful.

As an example:

- 100GB of blob storage
- 100GB of tables and queues
- 10 million transactions per month

is a grand total of $9.90 USD per month.